# Xamarin.Android happens error on Android 7

Tags: android, xamarin, android-7.0-nougat

I'm using Xamarin.Android to development application in my project. When I build app on all version bellow Android 7, no problem happens. But when running on Android 7. It happens error: Detected problem with app native libraries (please consult log for detail): libmonosgen-2.0.so: unauthorized access to "/system/lib/libsqlite.so".

How to fix it? Please help me!!!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Changes have been made in regards to native linking which SQLite unfortunately is affected by as read [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/preparing-for-native-library-linking-changes-in-android-n/).

The the reason your application crashes is due to the fact, that Android Nougat now no longer allows to dynamically linking against non-NDK libraries; something which SQLite did previously. By updating SQLite, the issue should be resolved. Although, do note that other libraries that you use could be affected by this change as well.

You will also have to inspect every `PInvoke` that you do yourself.

If that's the case, then you also have to option of decreasing the `targetSdkVersion` in the manifest for your given Android project to `23`. Doing so will simply write a warning to the console instead of throwing a runtime error.